# A collection containing some specific string, but having list of Strings

Tags: junit, collections, hamcrest, assertthat

I've implemented this method:

```
@FindBy(partialLinkText = "Avocode")
List<WebElement> results;

public List<String> getSearchResults (){
    List<String> text = results.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return text;
}
```

Then I have a test trying to find any match with 'avocode':

```
assertThat(find.getSearchResults(),IsCollectionContaining.hasItem("Avocode"));
```

My imported libraries:

```
import org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pageObjects.Search;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

++
My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.11</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
<artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I expect that test will run successfully, although I'm getting:

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>   Expected: a collection containing "Avocode"
>
> but: was "Avocode \"ready to eat\" DUO pack", was "Avocode Hass, was "Avocode Fuerte", was "Avocode Bacon"

I believe I have followed all tips here in stack-overflow, but nothing is working - Avocode is there, so it should pass...

I will appreciate any help (I'm new in programming).

Thanks,
Lijana

Comment: use startsWith("Avocado")  `assertThat(find.getSearchResults(),IsCollectionContaining.hasItem(startsWith("Avocado") ));`

Comment: Hello Dirk, 
thanks a lot, that passed! But I can imagine situations when it doesn't start with that specified string, it could be anywhere, I just need one good match. 

So I don't really understand why this is having error:
...,IsCollectionContaining.hasItem("Avocode"));

..you do?

Comment: List<String> ingredients = Arrays.asList("Appel",**"Avocado"**,"Rice");
   assertThat(ingredients,IsCollectionContaining.hasItem(**"Avocado"**));
    
    List<String> menu = Arrays.asList("Appel pie",**"Avocado salade"**,"Rice & chicken");
    assertThat(menu,IsCollectionContaining.hasItem(**startsWith("Avocado") )**); `

Comment: _**Avocado**_ is not equals to _**Avocado "ready to eat" DUO pack**_,
but **Avocado "ready to eat" DUO pack** starts with _**Avocado**_

Comment: Yeah, I know I have to use only **hasItem("Avocode"));**, but for that I'm getting an error :( 
Maybe it's connected to *List<WebElement>* results; but I solve it by converting to list...
.collect(Collectors.toList()); 

Hope you understand me now.